# How do I run Windows or Linux as a virtual machine on Android?

Tags: linux, windows, emulators, virtualbox, virtualization

I would like to run Windows XP as a virtual machine on my Android tablet.  Since Android is based on Linux, is it possible to compile VirtualBox to run in Android?  If not possible, is it possible to run WinXP as a virtual machine in any way on an Android tablet?

Comment: Related:  [Can I virtualize Windows on an x86 Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/149192/131868)

Comment: None of the emulation options are even capable of smooth and *usable* W95/98. You might've overestimated the power of the phone and emulators.

Comment: Not all processors are equal. There is a thing called ARM.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/84359/218526, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55376, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174938

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page). Apparently it's [known to run on ARM.](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2012-01/msg02354.html) 
Running XP (if it even works) is probably not going to be a pleasant experience due to what's noted by Chris Herbert and the probable lack of a screen/pointer driver. 
If you really want to do it maybe wait for the Intel Atom (x86) based tablets. There should be some Atom based Windows 8 tablets about now. The androids are [coming soon](http://www.electronista.com/articles/12/01/11/k2110.pairs.medfield.hardware.with.ics/).

Answer (score 20):

VirtualBox uses virtualization, which isn't possible when the host device (Android tablet) uses a different CPU architecture than the guest device (x86 PC running windows XP). Since your android tablet almost certainly has an ARM CPU, the x86 CPU would have to be emulated, which is massively slower than virtualization. It doesn't seem like it would be practical at all.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I've been working with Google TV forgot that the Tablets don't use x86.

Comment: What about running another Android (or Debian ARM)?

Comment: @f.ardelian Yes, apps such as Nonroot Debian and Complete Linux Installer let you run GNU userland on Android without emulation.

Comment: Actually, many Android devices are now x86, so it's now [technically](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/149192/131868) possible. @f.ardelian

Comment: I disagree with the premise that virtualization requires something about CPU architecture at all. I mean, there's x86 emulator in javascript and it can run w98 and MSDOS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try [DOSBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fishstix.dosbox&hl=en), a MS-DOS, Windows 95/98/XP capable emulator based off QEMU. It will emulate something close to a 1st-generation Pentium, so don't expect it to be fast even if you run it on, say, a Nexus 9 (but it could be usable). [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=44730248) has some tricks to up the performance somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to run full windows applications under [wine](https://lifehacker.com/you-can-run-these-windows-apps-on-android-with-wine-3-0-1822342695) on android.  It supports some applications it is an emulator originally for Linux desktop and ported also for android as its also Linux. They list applications that can run on [xda-developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092348)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Limbo emulator or Qemu. but i don't think that your phone can handle windows 10. i've tried windows xp though and it worked pretty well.