# How to run virtual machine on my nexus device?

Tags: virtualization, arm-processors

Are there any virtual machine players such as virtualbox, I can use to run `.iso` images on Android? If I need the device to be rooted that is fine, but I prefer a portable solution

Comment: A `.iso` file is just a way of storing a filesystem in a single file. Does your filesystem contain a kernel and binaries for the processor inside your phone (usually a version of the ARM architecture), or for some different processor (such as i386)?

Comment: I want to run a linux image

Comment: But is the Linux image for Intel PCs or for ARM processors? It makes a big difference.

Comment: It is of course for X86 but I will compile it for ARM, is it possible at all to run X86 compiled kernel on ARM using VM ?

Comment: Duplicate [How do I run Windows or Linux as a virtual machine on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30165/how-do-i-run-windows-or-linux-as-a-virtual-machine-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which OS you want to run. Regardless, whenever you want to run a OS meant for computers (x86 architecture) on a mobile device (ARM architecture) a fair amount of time and processing power is needed to convert instructions from one format to other.

I'm not sure if there is a one stop solution like VMware on Android like that can run both *Nix and Windows OS's.

You can try the app [Windows, Linux, Unix Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motioncoding.emulator&hl=en&referrer=utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_term=run%20windows%20in%20android) but I'm not sure how far it will be successful.

Comment: I want to run a linux image