# Can I virtualize Windows on an x86 Android device?

Tags: windows, android-x86, virtualization, remix-os, x86-processors

I've read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/30165/131868), and of course, there, the answer was "you can't, because the architecture is different."

But that's not necessarily the case anymore. Many Android devices, [like mine](http://www.asuszenfoneblog.com/2015/01/asus-zenfone-2-ze551ml-full-phone-spesification.html), now have x86 processors and also the specs to run Windows. Thanks to [Remix OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remix_OS) and [Android x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android-x86), many x86 desktop computers (and tablets, etc.) now run Android.

So, is there any way to virtualize Windows on Android if you have an x86 device?

Comment: Never tried, and might be limited – but you might wish to take a look at [Limbo PC Emulator](https://github.com/limboemu/limbo).

Comment: @Izzy Is performance significantly better than emulating PC on ARM? (QEMU?)

Comment: You're asking me? Please read the first two words of my previous comments :)

Comment: @Izzy Haha... Yeah, alright. Maybe someone else knows.

Comment: Duplicate: [Is there any virtualization software that will run under Android on an x86 device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84359/is-there-any-virtualization-software-that-will-run-under-android-on-an-x86-devic)