# How do you run a virtual machine in Android?

Tags: virtualization

I had an idea, run Chromium OS on Android. I got myself a tablet off eBay and I am wondering how do I create a virtual machine on the tablet itself. The image is a .`img` or I can get it as a `.vdi` if needed. I am stuck at what to do now.

Do I need an app for the tablet (Acer Iconia Tab 8) or do I need to root it to do anything?

Comment: I'll give my 100 points to  one who can come up with a positive working answer to this question. (My Device is OnePlus One). // My bet is the solution doesn't exist.

Comment: my issue now is my tablet is not 86x.

Comment: You don't need root running a VM. Just sit back, relax. A VM will pop up eventually.

Comment: you would think some one made one by now

Comment: Would love to know the answer...

Comment: I have try all day and got a little closer, I have a solution I'm trying now.

Comment: Duplicate [How do I run Windows or Linux as a virtual machine on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30165/how-do-i-run-windows-or-linux-as-a-virtual-machine-on-android)