# How to run Windows 10 in a virtual box on an Android phone?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I use my phone for communications and work on the go. I use a windows 10 tablet connected to external mouse/keyboard and monitor. Many programs such as email and contacts etc., are duplicated on each hardware.

Is it likely to be possible to run Windows 10 in a virtual box on an Android device, - so I can still use the Android phone for communication and emulated Windows 10 with the external monitor/keyboard for desktop use at the same time?

Virtual box, I mean something like Oracle’s Virtual Machine which lets you run other operating systems in a window on top of the main operating system.

Comment: Duplicate [How do I run Windows or Linux as a virtual machine on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30165/how-do-i-run-windows-or-linux-as-a-virtual-machine-on-android)